# Command "new" and "malloc" are not allocating memory correctly

Tags: c++, c

Below is my simple code taken from dozens of SO questions, forums etc. The same was done for `malloc` for C, with exactly the same result. My pointer (to be used as array) is being created as only ptr[0], as illustrated in the picture. Any ideas what it could be?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int x = 5;
    double* ptr = new double[x];
    // At this point the debugger displays the pointer as pointing at a single
    // double, not five doubles.
    delete[] ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Btw, unfortunately I need to work with arrays. I am calling an API that requires C (for now). Thank you for any help.

Debugging of aforementioned code with wrong dynamic allocation

[image: Debugging of aforementioned code with wrong dynamic allocation]

Comment: I don't see your problem. You allocate memory for `x` elements of type `double`. Each element is uninitialized. And you get a pointer to *the first* element. Just like it should be. Perhaps you want a `std::vector` (from which you [can easily get a pointer to the first element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) which you can pass to a C function).

Comment: Your assumption is this ptr[0]? Is this debugger display?

Comment: A raw pointer does not know the difference between pointing to a single value and pointing to an array of values.  Your debugger is just showing you the what the raw pointer points to, which is the 1st element of the array.

Comment: You might try assigning distinct values to the elements and then use expressions to check them again like `ptr + 1`. The picture you posted looks like a piece of MSVC, there is an apprpriate expression widget *somewhere*...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is very clear now. The mistake was conceptual from my side.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem with malloc or new in your code. ptr has been allocated memory enough to store 5 double values. You should try adding values in the array and try fetching them. What you see while debugging is the way debugger displays pointers. If you want to see all elements in debugger then you should create an array and not pointer e.g. **double arr[5]**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int x = 5;
double* ptr = new double[x];

ptr[0] = 1.1;
ptr[1] = 1.2;
ptr[2] = 1.3;
ptr[3] = 1.4;
ptr[4] = 1.5;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    cout << ptr[i] << endl;

delete[] ptr;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need an array to be created dynamically. And the mistake is from my said, conceptually. Thanks again.

Comment: It would also help to just add `ptr[1]` etc. to watched variables list.